# How to change arrow point header in paint flutter?

Tags: flutter, paint, custom-painter

[image]

I need to change the arrow head with double line.

Comment: You need to share the code that you did so far?

Comment: void drawArrow(Canvas canvas, Offset start, Offset end, Paint painter){
  final arrowPainter = Paint()
    ..color =painter.color
    ..strokeWidth =painter.strokeWidth
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
  canvas.drawLine(start, end, painter);
  final _pathOffset = painter.strokeWidth / 15;
  var path = Path()
    ..lineTo(-15 * _pathOffset, 10 * _pathOffset)
    ..lineTo(-15 * _pathOffset, -10 * _pathOffset)
    ..close();
  canvas.save();
  canvas.translate(end.dx, end.dy);
  canvas.rotate((end - start).direction);
  canvas.drawPath(path, arrowPainter);
  canvas.restore();
}

Comment: @MarlenFranto You should add your code to your question by editing it. And please format it using the code tags.